# Как обратиться к функции iframe'а?

Tags: jquery, iframe, javascript

Как мне из родительского документа обратиться к функции, объявленной в iframe?
На нативном JS или с jQuery - без разницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
document.getElementById("идВашегоФрейма").contentWindow.вашаФункция();
```

Работает во всех современных браузерах.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и делал, но, похоже, где-то ошибся и отбросил этот способ. Сейчас заново попробовал - всё ок.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.frames['FrameName'].someFunction();
```

Но это возможно при условии, что домен родителя и фрейма теже